# Linq query - ON clause of inner join cannot compare two Guids

Tags: linq

If the person you are searching is a CIA emplyee, take his CIAJobs.EmployerID, otherwise select People.ID

```
SELECT 
    case when CIAJobs.EmployeeID IS NULL then People.ID
    else CIAJobs.EmployerID
    end

    FROM  [FMO].[People] AS p
    LEFT JOIN [FMO].[CIAJobs] j

        ON (p.ID = j.[EmployeeID]) 
        AND (j.[relationshipType] = '25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63') 

    where p.ID = '1b66e032-94b2-e811-96e0-f48c508e38a2' // id of person you search for
            OR 
     j.[EmployeeID] =   '1b66e032-94b2-e811-96e0-f48c508e38a2' // id of person you search for
```

I tried doing this in Linq:

```
    var a = from l in People
            join x in CIAJobs
            on l.Id equals x.EmployeeID && x.RelationshipTypeGuid equals Guid.Parse('25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63')
            into gcomplex
            from xx in gcomplex.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select (xx.EmployeeID == null) ? l.EmployeeId : x.EmployerID;
    var b = a.ToList();
```

why does the query show an error because of this chunk: `&& x.RelationshipTypeGuid equals Guid.Parse('25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63')`
    If I remove this part it shows no error.
Error is: operator && cannot be applied to operands of type Guid and Guid.

Can you help me correct the Linq query please logically and syntactically? Thank you.

Comment: what are u using `RelationshipTypeGuid` for?

Comment: Try to use x.RelationshipTypeGuid.Equals(Guid.Parse('25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63') or put the join condition in braces like this ((l.Id equals x.EmployeeID) && (x.RelationshipTypeGuid equals Guid.Parse('25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63')))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `join` for multiple conditions in this scenario. Use this

```
var a = from l in People
        join x in CIAJobs
                  .Where(z=>z.RelationshipTypeGuid
                  .Equals(Guid.Parse('25a8d79d-377e-4108-8c92-0ef9a2e1ab63')))
        on l.Id equals x.EmployeeID
        into gcomplex
        from xx in gcomplex.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select (xx.EmployeeID == null) ? l.EmployeeId : x.EmployerID;
    var b = a.ToList();
```

But based on your problem statement this should do

```
var a = from l in People
        join x in CIAJobs
        on l.Id equals x.EmployeeID
        into gcomplex
        from xx in gcomplex.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select (xx == null) ? l.EmployeeId : xx.EmployerID;
    var b = a.ToList();
```